# Jquery validation code for check box in table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation, checkbox

[image: Image of skills required]
From the above image i have added more functionality, 
So my question is for every skill  GD (or) PI (or) both checkboxes has to be mandatory.(Atleast one checkbox has to be selected)
how can i achieve that.?
this is my html:

```
<a class="text-center btn btn-danger addSkills">+ Add Skills</a>
<input class="selectGdSkill" type="checkbox" count="0" id="skill[0][gdskill]" name="skill[0][gdskill]">
<input class="selectPiSkill" type="checkbox" count="0" id="skill[0][piskill]" name="skill[0][piskill]">
```

this is add more functionality code:

```
var skillcount = 1;
$(".addSkills").click(function () {
    $('#jobSkills tr:last').after('<tr>
    <td><input class="searchskill" count="' + skillcount + '" id="skill_' + skillcount + '_title" name="skill[' + skillcount + '][title]" type="text" autocomplete="off"></td><td><input count="' + skillcount + '" id="skill_' + skillcount + '_weightage" name="skill[' + skillcount + '][weightage]" type="text" autocomplete="off"></td>
    <td><select class="wp-form-control" name="skill[' + skillcount + '][type]"><option value="0">Select Test Type</option><option value="1">Practice Test</option><option value="2">Qualifying</option></select></td>
    <td><input  class="selectGdSkill" type="checkbox" count="' + skillcount + '" id="skill[' + skillcount + '][gdskill]" name="skill[' + skillcount + '][gdskill]"></td>
    <td> <input class="selectPiSkill" type="checkbox" count="' + skillcount + '" id="skill[' + skillcount + '][piskill]" name="skill[' + skillcount + '][piskill]"></td>
    <td><span class="removeSkill" id="' + skillcount + '" ><a style="color:red">Remove</a></span></td>
    </tr>');
    skillcount++;
});
```

help me in fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r359b453/6/

Comment: I'd consider using browser validations like `<input class="selectGdSkill" type="checkbox" count="0" id="skill[0][gdskill]" name="skill[0][gdskill]" required>` They have pretty good support http://caniuse.com/#search=required

Comment: @23tux - Except the individual checkboxes aren't mandatory, the requirement is that each row have at least one checkbox checked.

Comment: `$("tr").each(function() { if ($(this).find(":checked").length === 0) { ... } })` - or something like that that counts the checked items within a given row?

Comment: I this setup using a table? if so can you show how the rows are arranged? You can do what you are asking, just need more context on the layout.

Comment: @nnnnnn it is not working can you provide full answer in bottom.?

Answer (score 3):

Here Your HTML I have changed input box IDs and put your table 
`<div id="myDiv">
    <table id="tableID">
    <tr>
     GD<input class="selectGdSkill" type="checkbox" id="selectGdSkill_0"> 
     PI<input class="selectPiSkill" type="checkbox" id="selectPiSkill_1">
    </tr>
    <br>
    <tr>
    GD<input class="selectGdSkill" type="checkbox"  id="selectGdSkill_1"> 
    PI<input class="selectPiSkill" type="checkbox"  id="selectPiSkill_1">
    </tr>
    </table>
    <button id="JobSubmit" class="btn btn-success text-center">SUBMIT JOB</button>
</div>`

Here is javascript code for check.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#JobSubmit").on("click",function(){          
        var IDs = [];
        $("#myDiv").find("input").each(function(){ IDs.push(this.id); });
         console.log(IDs);

         $.each(IDs, function(i, value) {
            if(!($("#"+value ).is(":checked"))){
                alert("Atleast one checkbox has to select from every tr");
                return false;
            }

         });

    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Give same class name to all checkbox and try this one

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submitBTN").click(function(e) {                 
        if($('.case:checkbox:checked').length==0){
            alert("Please select");                 
        }         
    });
});
```

Comment: For Every dynamilly created skill `<tr>`   
i want some what like this..? `if($('.selectGdSkill || .selectPiSkill :checkbox:checked').length==0){`

Answer (score 1):

**If Both checkboxes are empty for every skill say select atleast on checkbox**

```
  var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var isTableValid = true;
    for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++) {
        var checkboxs=rows[i].getElementsByClassName("selectGdSkill");//add "selectPiSkill" class in this
        var okay=false;
        for(var j=0;j<checkboxs.length;j++){
            console.log('here' + checkboxs[j].checked);
            if(checkboxs[j].checked){
                okay=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!okay && checkboxs.length > 0) {
            isTableValid = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(isTableValid)
    return true;
    else
    {
        alert("Please select atleast one checkbox every skill either GD or PI");
        return false;
    }
```

it is workking for every `<tr>` but only for `selectGdSkill` And

> i am  looking for Anyone from the two checkboxes GD (or) PI